# Passing props to component in React Router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react-router and I just started writing an app using react-router V4. I would like to to pass props to components rendered by `<Match />` and I am wondering about what's the 'best' or 'proper' way to do so.

Is it by doing something like this?

```
<Match pattern="/" render={
    (defaultProps) => <MyComponent myProp = {myProp} {...defaultProps} />
}/>
```

Is this (passing props to components to be rendered by `<Match />`) even a good practice to do so with react-router or is it an antipattern or something; and if so, why?

Comment: looks good for me.

Answer (score 11):

You must use the `render` prop instead of `component` to pass on custom props, otherwise only [default Route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/Route-props) are passed (`{match, location, history}`).

I pass my props to the Router and child components like so.

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const {another} = this.props
    return <Routes myVariable={2} myBool another={another}/>
  }
}

const Routes = (props) =>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/public" render={ (routeProps) => 
      <Public routeProps={routeProps} {...props}/>
    }/>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
    <PrivateRoute path="/" render={ (routeProps) =>
       ...
    }/>
  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
render() {
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" 
           render={ ()  => <Header 
             title={"I am Title"} 
             status={"Here is my status"}
           /> }
        />
        <Route path="/audience" component={Audience}/>
        <Route path="/speaker" component={Speaker}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: Might not relevant to your q? but in react router 4 its work around way to do it  till.

Comment: It looks like your comment should be part of your answer.

Comment: Yup,In react router v4 many changes, you would not except it  will be work as before used to be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to react-router and came across a similar issue. I've created a wrapper based on the [Documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) and that seems to work.

```
// Wrap Component Routes
function RouteWrapper(props) {
  const {component: Component, ...opts } = props

  return (
   <Route {...opts} render={props => (
     <Component {...props} {...opts}/>
   )}/>
 )
}

 <RouteWrapper path='/' exact loggedIn anotherValue='blah' component={MyComponent} />
```

So far so good

Comment: i tried to implement something similar to this based on another example in github, issues i've had is: a component being rendered when the props are api calls resets the states to empty values

Answer (score 0):

I use `render` in combination with a defined method like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  childRoute (ChildComponent, match) {
    return <ChildComponent {...this.props} {...match} />
  }

  render () {
    <Match pattern='/' render={this.childRoute.bind(this, MyComponent)} />
  }
}
```

Comment: You rebind the component every time the render is called.

Answer (score 0):

The `render` prop is meant for writing inline matches, so your example is the ideal way to pass extra props.

Comment: Is is better to use `component` instead of `render` in this case?

Comment: @Qwerty I just edited my answer to remove that comment. If you are using an inline function, you should also use `render`. Doing that with `component` is really inefficient (you'll be unmounting/mounting a new component every render).

Answer (score -1):

I'll do it like the following to improve clarity.

```
const myComponent = <MyComponent myProp={myProp} {...defaultProps} />


<Match pattern="/" component={myComponent} />
```

By this your `router` code won't get messed up!.

Comment: Is this valid? The [documentation](https://react-router.now.sh/Match) says that `render` takes a function while in your example you are passing a component instance

Comment: My bad! Updated the answer!

Comment: Hmm, sorry to ask again, but is this still valid? According to the documentation, `component` takes a component *constructor*, while you are supplying a component instance

Comment: It is valid. They are also passing the compnent.

Comment: Whether valid or not, you are passing in a React Element. Not a component or an instance.

Comment: @kentor I'm sorry, is there a difference between React element and a component. I think you should read the documentation properly.

Comment: Yes: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html We should be very careful to use the right vocabulary

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis It's not valid. React throwed an exception for me (version 16.2). I also tried to set `component` with a lamda `() => <MyComponent...` and ended up with `componentWillReceiveProps` not firing silently for the component. The right way is to follow the accepted answer.