# React Router 4 passing props through Route render doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This question has been asked, but [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871662/passing-props-to-component-in-react-router-4) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component?rq=1) aren't solving this for me. I want to pass the `signInWithEmail` handler function from my `<App />` component down through `<Layout />` and then to the `<SignIn />` component via a `<Route />`.

The way to do this is apparently via the `render` attribute on the Route, but for me it just renders ignores my `onSubmit`. In React dev tools I just see the default Route props, even though I can see my handler function(s) in the `<Layout />` element showing up as `props.signInWithEmail`. They don't make it to the `<SignIn />` element.

What am I missing? Thanks.

```
const Layout = (props) => (
// i can console.log(props) here and see props.signInWithEmail
  <div className="layout">
    // header etc...
    <main>
      <Switch>
       // ... other routes
        <Route
          path="/signin"
          render= {(props) => <SignIn onSubmit={props.signInWithEmail} />}           
        />
      </Switch>
    </main>
    // footer etc...
  </div>
)}
```

render part of App:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Layout 
            signInWithEmail={this.signInWithEmail} 
            signUpWithEmail={this.signUpWithEmail} 
            signOut={this.signOut} 
            state={this.state}
          />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you share how you're passing the props into the `Layout` component

Comment: Show your app component please.

Comment: Sure, I've added the app component where it's passed in, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you overriding props within arrow function.
Try to destructure Layout prop like that:

```
const Layout = ({signInWithEmail}) => (
// i can console.log(props) here and see props.signInWithEmail
  <div className="layout">
    // header etc...
    <main>
      <Switch>
       // ... other routes
        <Route
          path="/signin"
          render= {() => <SignIn onSubmit={signInWithEmail} />}           
        />
      </Switch>
    </main>
    // footer etc...
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: Yes that did it, glad it was simple, can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks.